# How to assign Global Administrator role to a Service Principal in Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-service-principal

I can assign the owner role to a service principal

```
# Assign Owner Permission to the Service Principal
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sp-tenant-global-admin-role-assignment" {
  scope                = "subscriptions/${data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id}"
  role_definition_name = "Owner"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.sp-tenant-global-admin.object_id
}
```

However, I want to assign the Global Administrator role, the below Terraform code fails

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sp-tenant-global-admin-role-assignment" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.current.tenant_id
  role_definition_name = "Global Administrator"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.sp-tenant-global-admin.object_id
}
```

How to assign Global Administrator role to a Service Principal in Azure?

Comment: Are you trying to assign Azure AD Global Administrator role?

Comment: Yes, so that this account will have access to create the management group and perform AD connection

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- You almost definitely DON'T want to grant a service principal this role!!! Service Principals (any AAD object for that matter) should always be granted RBAC roles under least privilege principle. Even `Owner` sounds excessive, can I ask why you want to give an App Registration this high of a role?
- That aside, what is the role of the service connection's service principal? It cannot grant roles greater than itself (this could be the issue potentially). Can you link/screenshot/dump the error you get from Terraform?

Comment: I am building an Azure devops pipeline which would setup the management group, Subscriptions, networking, AD connection. Can you please recommend the suitable permission to be granted to the service principal which will be used to create the service connection?

Comment: I think what you actually might want is something like [Azure Blueprints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/overview)

Answer (score 1):

The terraform service principal (the one that CI/CD pipelines are using) sometimes needs `Global Admin` permissions.
The way to create it in terraform is to add `azuread_directory_role` & `azuread_directory_role_assignment`

```
resource "azuread_directory_role" "global_admin" {
  display_name = "Global Administrator" #or any other directory role
}

resource "azuread_directory_role_assignment" "sp_directory_role_assignment" {
  role_id             = azuread_directory_role.global_admin.template_id
  principal_object_id = azuread_service_principal.primary_sp.object_id
}
```

Comment: And btw you need both `azurerm_role_assignment` to the subscriptuon & `Global Admin` for users, groups & sp creation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).